# c# openxml datatable exported to excel causes repair when used in spreadsheet comparer utility in windows 10 office 2019

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, openxml, openxml-sdk

no repair issue when I open in excel application
only spreadsheetcomparer complains for read past stream

[error messgae spreadsheetcomparer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEIiL.png)

has anyone faced this issue earlier what we can do for it to fix from openxml library perspective

edit1

I will try to give more detail,
When I compare repaired and non repaired excel winmerge says identical may be wirmerge checks only text inside excel
When I open excels in openxml sdk one difference I see is docProps/core.xml is missing in non-repaired version
I will try this adding,If anyone has more details on core props to add from c# openxml that can help, may be this can be new question

edit 2
When I open excels in openxml sdk
following parts are also missing under xl/workbookk
theme and sharedstrings is missing

Comment: Please add some code how to reproduce your issue and maybe provide an example excel file which can be checked. Also, what is spreadsheetcomparer and where can one find it? Only a few SO users can read minds... I can not.

Comment: spreadsheet comparer shows on windows once office is installed, or we need to enable inquire addin once office installed https://gaylelarson.com/analyze-or-compare-workbook-versions-with-spreadsheet-inquire/